# How to create a portable VSCode launch configuration for Ansible Playbook debugging?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ansible, vscode-debugger

I am working on the development of Ansible Plugins with a team of developers. Some are using Windows, others Linux. We rely on Visual Studio Code as IDE. We use [`pipenv`](https://pipenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) for defining our development environment.

What I'd like to achieve is a to have a debug configuration (`launch.json`) which works for all developers without modification (and therefore be safely committed to the git repo).

The `ansible-playbook` command we'd like to use for our debugging is a symlink to a [stub file](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.6/lib/ansible/cli/scripts/ansible_cli_stub.py), and the actual functionality is defined by [`sys.argv[0]`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.10.6/lib/ansible/cli/scripts/ansible_cli_stub.py#L69).

The VSCode Python extension allows [debugging](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging) by either specifying a Python file or a module (`python3 -m <module>`). For my approach I'd prefer the latter, because it wouldn't require an actual path. While `python3 -m ansible.cli.scripts.ansible_cli_stub` invokes the proper module, it just doesn't work because of the `sys.argv[0]` value not matching `ansible-playbook`. Creating a launch configuration pointing to the `ansible-playbook` symlink as source file works, but isn't portable because of the different virtual environment locations of the different developers.

Do you have any idea how we could create a portable `launch.json` with a run configuration corresponding to `ansible-playbook some-playbook.yml`?

Answer (score 1):

`launch.json`

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Ansible Playbook",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "bin/run.py",
            "args": [
                "playbooks/test.yml",
                "-i", "inventory_dir"
            ],
            "env": {
                "ANSIBLE_VAULT_PASSWORD_FILE": "your_vault_password_file",
            },
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

`bin/run.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
from ansible.cli.playbook import PlaybookCLI

def main():
    cli = PlaybookCLI(sys.argv)
    cli.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Would be nice if `python -m ansible.playbook` or something similar worked.